# Getting the date representation in seconds in Java

Tags: java, sybase, sap-ase

I have a date For `Eg: 2014-04-22 08:22:41` and I have to get the representation of the date in seconds from GMT-5 timezone which is `12/31/1969 19:00:00`.

I have the following code:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class samp {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-5:00"));
        long temp;
        Date tempDate = null;

        temp = 0L;
        cal.clear();
        try {
            tempDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse("2014-04-22 08:22:41");
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        cal.setTime(tempDate);
        temp = cal.getTimeInMillis() / 1000L;
        cal.clear();

        System.out.println("Second representation is " + (int) temp);

    }
}
```

The output is : Second representation is  1398135161

But when I get the same value from Sybase Database I get the value:

```
select DateDiff(ss,'12/31/1969 19:00:00','04/22/2014 08:22:41') = 1398172961
```

Why is there a difference between the java result and the database value.

Is there something wring in java code.

Please clarify.

Comment: remove L from 1000L.
May it will help

Comment: I tried your code and I got this: Second representation is 1398147761, not 1398135161 as you mention. My local timezone is Europe/Prague, which is GMT+2.

Comment: @Michal The code is dependent of the UTC time set at your machine. Obviously, you run your code at a different time than him and therefore you got a different time.

Answer (score 0):

As you can find at the oracle documentation site:
[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTimeInMillis()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTimeInMillis%28%29)

`getTimeInMillis` returns the time in UTC

You can adjust that value to your timezone using:

```
cal.getTimeZone().getOffset(UTCmilliseconds)
```

Which (as it is described at [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getOffset(long)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getOffset%28long%29)) returns the amount of milliseconds you have to add to UTC time to get your localtime in milliseconds.

Being your zone-adjusted time given by:

```
cal.setTime(tempDate);
temp = cal.getTimeInMillis();
temp = (temp + (long)(cal.getTimeZone().getOffset(temp)))/ 1000L;
```

Answer (score 0):

They are using different timezones

your database is working off of your set timezone but in your calendar you are not using the same timezone when you get the millis.

1398135161 * 1000 can equal in millis

```
Date (America/New_York) Monday, April 21, 2014 10:52:41 PM EDT
Date (GMT)  Tuesday, April 22, 2014 2:52:41 AM GMT
```

it is all relative to timezone.

There are websites like these that can help you out when in doubt
http://www.ruddwire.com/handy-code/date-to-millisecond-calculators/#.U1dtG-bqfCc
http://www.fileformat.info/tip/java/date2millis.htm

Answer (score 0):

## Adjust Date-Time, Not Epoch

You should be thinking about adjusting your date-time value not the epoch.

## Use Time Zone, Not Offset

You should probably be using proper time zone names, not a specific offset number because of Daylight Saving Time and other anomalies. Unless you are absolutely certain your date-values were always adjusted by that specific offset.

## Avoid j.u.Date

You should be using a decent library rather than the notoriously difficult java.util.Date and .Calendar classes. That means either Joda-Time or the new java.time package in Java 8.

## Joda-Time

Here is example code in Joda-Time.

```
String inputRaw = "2014-01-02 12:34:56";
String input = inputRaw.replace( " ", "T" );
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Detroit" );
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( input, timeZone );
long millis = dateTime.getMillis();
Long seconds = ( millis / 1000L );
```